# kivy gridlayout can't remove or add widgets after first entry

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I'm trying to clear the gridlayoutexample to then add new things to it but when I go in the layout for the 2th time I can't add or remove anything

python file:

```
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.stacklayout import StackLayout
from calendar import monthrange
import calendar
import datetime



current_time = datetime.datetime.now()
year = current_time.year
month_int = current_time.month
weekheader = str(calendar.weekheader(3))
days = weekheader.split(" ")
days_length = len(days)



class GridLayoutExample(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        global eerste
        self.clear_widgets()
        num_days = monthrange(year, month_int)[1]
        month = calendar.monthcalendar(year, month_int)
        start_day = month[0].count(0)
        for j in range(days_length):
            label1 = Label(text=days[j], color=(0, 0, 0, 1))
            self.add_widget(label1)
        
        for g in range(start_day):
            label2 = Label()
            self.add_widget(label2)
        
        for i in range(num_days):
            button = Button(text=str(i + 1))
            button.my_id = str(i + 1) + "-" + str(month_int) + "-" + str(year)
            self.ids[str(i + 1) + "-" + str(month_int) + "-" + str(year)] = button
            self.add_widget(button)            


class LayoutExample(StackLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        for l in range(10):
            label4 = Label(text="zeer plezant \n \n \n ha", size = self.size, color=(0, 0, 0, 1), size_hint=(None, None))
            self.add_widget(label4)
            button = Button(text="wijzig", size_hint=(1, None), size=(100, 60))
            self.add_widget(button)
            button = Button(text="verwijder", size_hint=(1, None), size=(100, 60))
            self.add_widget(button)


class drop(MDApp):
    global year, month_int, current_time
    stryear = str(year)
    strmonth_int = str(month_int)
    print(year)
    def kies_maand(self, text):
        global month_int
        month_int = int(text)
        return GridLayoutExample()
    
    def kies_jaar(self, text):
        global year
        year = int(text)
        return GridLayoutExample()


drop().run()
```

kivy file:

```
#:kivy 1.0
PageLayoutExample:

<PageLayoutExample@PageLayout>:
    Gridspin:
    GridLayouttest:



<ScrollViewExample@ScrollView>:
    size: root.width, root.height
    LayoutExample:



<GridLayouttest@GridLayout>:
    rows: 3
    ScrollViewExample:
    TextInput:
        hint_text:'taak toevoegen'
        size_hint:(1, None) 
        height: 60
    Button:
        text:'toevoegen'
        size_hint:(1, None) 
        height: 60



<Gridspin@GridLayout>:
    rows: 2
    GridLayout:
        height: 60
        size_hint: 1, None
        cols: 2
        Spinner:
            height: 60
            size_hint: 1, None
            text: app.strmonth_int
            values: ['1', '2', '3', '4']
            on_text: app.kies_maand(self.text)
        Spinner:
            height: 60
            size_hint: 1, None
            text: app.stryear
            values: ['2018', '2019', '2020', '2021']
            on_text: app.kies_jaar(self.text)
    GridLayoutExample:



<GridLayoutExample>:
    id: grid
    #left-right  top-bottom
    cols: 7
    orientation: "lr-tb"
    size: root.minimum_width, root.minimum_height
    padding: ("20dp", "20dp", "20dp", "20dp")




<LayoutExample>:
    orientation: "lr-tb"
    size_hint: 1, None
    height: self.minimum_height
    width: self.width
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: 1, 1, 1, 1
        Rectangle:
            size: self.width, self.minimum_height
            pos: self.pos
```

I added self.clear_widgets but tha doesn't do anything. I also tried adding some buttons on a second entry and that still didn't do anything. I think I somehow am not creating or removing on the correct GUI screen somehow but I don't know how to change that

Comment: Where do you "go in the layout for the 2th time"?

Comment: I would assume when I return in the mdapp class. if  I put some print statements in the gridlayoutexample class they work when I return

Comment: The only method in the `GridLayoutExample` is the `__init__()` method which only gets executed once, when the `GridLayoutExample` is created.